# real-time thread-safe buffering algorithm

Tags: queue, real-time

I'm looking for an example/tutorial of a real-time thread-safe buffering algorithm (ie wait-free queue algorithms?). Looking in the web.. I found some pretty heavy duty master thesis [solutions](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~tsigas/papers/Real-Time-Java-queues-RTAS06.pdf). I need something (in 21st century english) it to solve a real time [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12462646/purge-the-contents-of-a-data-container-in-real-time) i'm working on. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the book [C++ Concurrency in Action](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988770) has a chapter dedicated to the implementations of such data structures.. and since objective C can use C++.. this works.